# Google Earth Pro: incorrect saving polygons with holes

Tags: polygon, kml, google-earth

I have problem with saving polygons in Google Earth Pro (MacOS 10.15.4, v.7.3.2.5776 (64-bit)). For example I made this polygon with holes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Polygon 0</name>
      <description>30.04.2020 20:40:05</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>A6000000</color>
          <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>33FFFFFF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>39.7496510240736,51.6331836277186,0 39.6344662090783,51.6403219871903,0 39.6334361136979,51.5869177649609,0 39.748105999541,51.585531107221,0 39.7496510240736,51.6331836277186,0 </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
        <innerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>39.6509456014809,51.6146402513385,0 39.649572457075,51.6309461040821,0 39.6736048549379,51.6296675530149,0 39.6730899257857,51.6128282791883,0 39.6509456014809,51.6146402513385,0 </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </innerBoundaryIs>
        <innerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>39.6976374898769,51.5971558936155,0 39.7003842528406,51.6131480947621,0 39.7180651465983,51.6113358855359,0 39.7232151493484,51.5970492093988,0 39.6976374898769,51.5971558936155,0 </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </innerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

It's correctly opens and viewed in Google Earth:
[image]

But when I'm saving this polygon to new KML file then holes are saved to one innerBoundaryIs block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
  <name>polygon_with_holes_ge.kml</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Polygon 0</name>
    <description>30.04.2020 20:40:05</description>
    <styleUrl>#stylemap_id0</styleUrl>
    <Polygon>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates> 39.7496510240736,51.6331836277186,0 39.6344662090783,51.6403219871903,0 39.6334361136979,51.5869177649609,0 39.748105999541,51.58553110722099,0 39.7496510240736,51.6331836277186,0 
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
      <innerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates> 39.6509456014809,51.6146402513385,0 39.649572457075,51.6309461040821,0 39.6736048549379,51.6296675530149,0 39.6730899257857,51.6128282791883,0 39.6509456014809,51.6146402513385,0 
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>39.6976374898769,51.5971558936155,0 39.7003842528406,51.6131480947621,0 39.7180651465983,51.6113358855359,0 39.7232151493484,51.5970492093988,0 39.6976374898769,51.5971558936155,0 
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </innerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

And this is not correct, because as schema defines there can be only one LinearRing  element in innerBoundaryIs (maxOccurs by default is 1):

```
<element name="innerBoundaryIs" type="kml:BoundaryType"/>
    <complexType name="BoundaryType" final="#all">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="kml:LinearRing" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element ref="kml:BoundarySimpleExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element ref="kml:BoundaryObjectExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

The problem is that later I'm importing this updated KML to my own system and the parser can see only first hole - in exact accordance to the schema.

How to fix it? Or it's Google Earth bug and I should report it there?